# Flashcards to learn Blackjack strategy table?

Tags: teaching, blackjack

I want to remember [this basic Blackjack strategy table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackjack#Basic_strategy).

Is there a flashcards deck to learn them? (by [spaced repetition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced_repetition))

Preferably in [Anki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anki) format, but other formats are fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are flash cards in the excellent book by Ken Uston titled "Million Dollar Blackjack"  This is a great book with interesting stories and strategies for different house rules.  Applies to counters and non-counters; single, double, and multiple deck games.  Vegas, Reno, AC rules explained as well.  I think you can find it for less than $20.
Good luck at the tables!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this is something you want/need?

Many casinos do not care if you play with the strategy card on the table in front of you. Some casinos also provide them if requested.

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110602191708AAVZtUx

http://www.blackjackinfo.com/bb/showthread.php?t=520

Comment: I did not know that, thanks! Even if referring to the table is allowed, memorizing it (which is a matter of only 10 minutes, thanks to SRS) would make the game less clumsy, more enjoyable, and allow to start thinking about better strategies in realtime.